# Keep rejecting my app because I don't clearly identify HealthKit functionality in my app's user interface

Tags: ios, healthkit, review

I've tried like 5 times with different combination of alert before the asking permission for writing on Health app (with the purpose: add workouts).

I also added an explicit phrase on app description and my `info.plist` has both `NSHealthShareUsageDescription` and `NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription` but they keep rejecting my app with this reason:

> ```
> Guideline 2.5.1 - Performance - Software Requirements
>
> Your app uses the HealthKit or CareKit APIs but does not indicate integration with the Health app in your app description and clearly identify the HealthKit and CareKit functionality in your app's user interface.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please clearly identify the HealthKit functionality in app's user interface to avoid confusion.
> ```

What can I do about it? In the last build I removed the HeathKit function so they maybe can approve with no other excuse but sooner or later I want to add this functionality...

Comment: Can you share what you currently have

Comment: They are not complaining about the app, but the "app description". This means the text for the App Store. You need to make it clear to buyers that the app will access data in the "Health" app.

Comment: Yes in my description I have: “This app integrates with the Health app to add your workouts data and show them in a beautiful way.“